# No page break when using hypertarget in custom environment

Tags: hyperref, page-breaking

I am trying to create an environment that would automatically create a label for each instance based on a global counter. This is the model example of what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcounter{TotalCounter}
\newenvironment{example}{
    \stepcounter{TotalCounter}
    \hypertarget{exampleRef\theTotalCounter}{\relax}
    \textbf{Example \theTotalCounter.}
}{}


\begin{document}

    \begin{example}This is an example.
    \end{example}

    \begin{example}This is an example.
    \end{example}

    \begin{example}This is an example.
    \end{example}

    % repeat this 100 times

\end{document}
```

However, when I run PDF-LaTex through this, the resulting document consists of one page with 57 examples going all the way to the bottom of the page. Of course, what I hoped was that after say, 45 examples there would be a page break, and the rest would continue on a new page. If I remove the hypertarget part, the problem disappears. Is there a simple way to modify this but still have the labeling system I defined in my environment.

Comment: Instead of a hypertarget you could use a normal label: `\phantomsection\refstepcounter{TotalCounter}\label{exampleRef\theTotalCounter}`. But it would be interesting to know how hyperref manages to suppress the page breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following definition for your `example`:

```
\newenvironment{example}{%
  \par
  \stepcounter{TotalCounter}%
  \hypertarget{exampleRef\theTotalCounter}{}%
  \textbf{Example \theTotalCounter.}
}{\par\penalty0}
```

It inserts a "`\par`agraph break" at the start and end of the environment, but also sets the `\penalty` for breaking across the page (at the end of the environment) to 0.

Note the use of `%` at the end of the definition lines (that aren't printed). This ensures you don't receive spurious spaces in your output.

Answer (score 3):

If you put the following lines

```
\showboxbreadth = 1000 %  more than necessary
\showboxdepth = 10 % much more than necessary
\showlists
```

after, say, the second occurence of

```
\begin{example}This is an example.
\end{example}
```

TeX will write in the transcript file a description of the vertical list it is building.  Looking at the beginning of this description, we find

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\write-{}
\pdfdest name{Doc-Start} xyz
\pdfdest name{exampleRef1} xyz
\glue(\topskip) 3.05556
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 183.73628fil
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 E
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 x
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 m
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 p
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 l
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
.\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91666 minus 1.27777
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 1
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 .
.\kern 0.0
.\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 T
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 m
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 p
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
\pdfdest name{exampleRef2} xyz
\penalty 10000
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 183.73628fil
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 E
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 x
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 a
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 m
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 p
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 l
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 e
.\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91666 minus 1.27777
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 2
.\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 .
```

etcetera.  Let us skip over the first six lines: the seventh one indicates the beginning of the `\hbox` (horizontal box) that contains the words “**Example 1.** This is an example.” (for each character, the font in which it is typeset is shown too).  The `\hbox` ends with the line that says

```
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

and, immediately following the box itself, we find

```
\pdfdest name{exampleRef2} xyz
```

This is the “destination” created with the `\hypertarget` command.  Now, the *hyperref* package inserts a `\penalty 10000` immediately below the destination, to explicitly prohibit a page break at that point, because such a break would detach the destination anchor from the material it is supposed to link to.  Without this, TeX could break the page at the next `\glue` item (the one marked `\parskip`), and indeed you have found that, without the `\hypertarget` command, everything works fine; but, as it stands, the vertical list shown above simply has *no* permissible breakpoint between paragraphs.  If the paragraphs were several lines long, however, there would be legal breakpoints *within* the paragraphs themselves.

Werner has already indicated a possible solution: insert permissible breakpoints “by hand” with `\penalty0` commands.  However, I would recommend the following redefinition

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{TotalCounter}
\newenvironment{example}{%
    \par
    \addpenalty{-\@lowpenalty}%
    \stepcounter{TotalCounter}%
    \hypertarget{exampleRef\theTotalCounter}{\relax}%
    \textbf{Example~\theTotalCounter.} % intentional
    \ignorespaces
}{
    \par
    \addpenalty{-\@lowpenalty}%
}
\makeatother
```

as more robust (`\addpenalty{-\@lowpenalty}` mildly encourages a page break either above or below the `example` environment).  Also, if you replace `\stepcounter` with `\refstepcounter`, you will be able to use the `\label`/`\ref` mechanism to reference your examples.